# How can i have a subscriber within a subscriber

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I need to subscribe to a topic within a subscriber, is this possible? and if so how can i accomplish it, thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/107296/how-can-i-have-a-subscriber-within-a-subscriber/) by [ctguell](https://answers.ros.org/users/5132/ctguell/) on ROS Answers with karma: 63 on 2013-12-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Can you clarify what it is you're trying to do and why? Typical pattern would be to subscribe to the two topics independently, cache one them using a shared_ptr, and do your processing for both in the second one's callback.

---

Originally posted by [mikepurvis](https://answers.ros.org/users/270/mikepurvis/) with karma: 1153 on 2013-12-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ctguell](https://answers.ros.org/users/5132/ctguell/) on 2013-12-12**:
@mikepurvis  Thanks a lot that worked, right now im having problem subscribing to /move_base/current_goal do you have any idea how to accomplish this?

**Comment by [mikepurvis](https://answers.ros.org/users/270/mikepurvis/) on 2013-12-16**:
Looks like you started a new question for this: http://answers.ros.org/question/107276/subscribing-to-move_basecurrent_goal/